# goconvey Please run goconvey from within your $GOPATH cannot import absolute path

Tags: go, goconvey

I'm setting up go and trying to get a simple project working with http://goconvey.co/

I have my $GOPATH set to /Users/joe/Desktop/playground/go

and when I run

> $ go get github.com/smartystreets/goconvey

it downloads all good to my GOPATH

so when I create a project here
/Users/joe/Desktop/playground/go/some-project

and run goconvey I get

```
2015/02/04 14:41:05 shell.go:93: Please run goconvey from within your $GOPATH
```

My testing code is

```
package main

import (
    . "github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey"
    "testing"
)

func TestStuff(t *testing.T) {
    Convey("Truth", t, func() {
        Convey("is falsey", func() {
            So(false, ShouldBeFalse)
        })
    })

}
```

I don't know why it connot find the files.
When I run go test it works perfectly.
Help?

Comment: Is your GOPATH symlinked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All go code needs to be within `$GOPATH/src/` for the GoConvey UI to work.

So, if your `$GOPATH` is set to

```
/Users/joe/Desktop/playground/go
```

then you will need to put your project at

```
/Users/joe/Desktop/playground/go/src/some-project
```

Your code is currently at

```
/Users/joe/Desktop/playground/go/some-project
```

Having said all that, the error message should probably be modified to read something like this:

> Please run goconvey from within $GOPATH/src (also, symlinks might be problematic).

The name of the variable referenced by @VonC is probably a slight misnomer in this case.

Comment: I've opened a new issue on the github repository: https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/issues/309

Comment: I removed my answer .+1

Comment: Given the misleading name of the const your intuition was spot on.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah would be good if the message was a little clearer.. Thanks for opening the issue

Comment: I've pushed a fix, which closed the issue I opened.